# Using .NET (3.5) Task Parallel Library in C++/ CLI

Tags: .net, concurrency, parallel-processing, task

Well, I download Reactive Extensions for NET 3.5 to use it in visual studio 2008 with c++/cli...

But all Task Parallel Library examples are in C#...I can not able to figure out EVEN converting that simple C# statements into C++/ CLI...

```
// use an Action delegate and a named method
Task task1 = new Task(new Action(printMessage));

// use a anonymous delegate
Task task2 = new Task(delegate {
printMessage();
});
```

**How can i write those statements in C++/CLI?**

Best Wishes

Comment: Hi, managed c++ is quite different from C#, do you have experience in writing managed c++ applications using .NET ?

Comment: No...Learning...So I ask it...  System.Action hola = () => Console.WriteLine("hola"); Many features does not exist in C++/ CLI

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#using <System.Core.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

ref class SomeTask {
public:
    static int run() {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Task<int>^ task = Task<int>::Factory->StartNew(gcnew Func<int>(&SomeTask::run));
    task->Wait();
    Console::WriteLine(task->Result);
    return 0;
}
```